# Does the term "witch-hunt" apply when referring to dealing with a real problem?

Tags: metaphors, cliche

Should the term "witch hunt" only be used when dealing with a problem that does not exist, as in witchcraft, or does the term also apply when a problem does exist, but those dealing with it are ignoring due process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition for *witch-hunt*, as given by the OED, is:

> a. A single-minded and uncompromising campaign against a group of people with unacceptable views or behaviour, spec. communists; esp. one regarded as unfair or malicious persecution.
>
> b. A campaign against an individual.

It has taken on this less literal meaning since the 1930s. The term is used to mean that a group of people is being persecuted for their beliefs unfairly. This can be used when there is a potential problem or not, but the group of "witches" is not being treated fairly. I think it is safe to say that the term applies to both of your cases: when there is no problem (like the Salem Witch Trials) and when due process is ignored (like communists in the US).

Comment: To be more explicit, what makes it a "witch hunt" has nothing to do with whether or not its a real problem, but has everything to do with whether or not due process is ignored -- if due process is ignored in a panic to accuse *someone*, *anyone*, it's a witch hunt.

Comment: @Jeremy: Exactly what I was trying to say. Only you put it much better.

Answer (score 1):

A "witch hunt" implies that someone is blamed for something that is not their fault. The problem may be real. But the source of the problem is not clear so a "scape goat" is found to take the blame.

Answer (score 0):

Witch hunt may refer to a situation where a person is targeted by a group with escalating intensity the end result threatens the person's integrity and survival.

Comment: You seem to have a valid answer; however, you should your source of information. This simply means to provide a link (i.e. http://www.merriam-webster.com/).